# R make new data frame from current one

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the best goal differentials in the group stage of the 2014 world cup.

```
football <- read.csv(
    file="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iTXdPvGf", 
    header = TRUE, 
    strip.white = TRUE
)
football <- head(football,n=48L)
football[which(max(abs(football$home_score - football$away_score)) == abs(football$home_score - football$away_score)),]
```

Results in

```
home home_continent home_score        away away_continent away_score result
4  Cameroon         Africa          0     Croatia         Europe          4      l
7     Spain         Europe          1 Netherlands         Europe          5      l
37  Germany
```

So those are the games with the highest goal differntial, but now I need to make a new data frame that has a team name, and `abs(football$home_score-football$away_score)`

Comment: football$score_diff <- abs(football$home_score-football$home_score) or newdata <- data.frame(football$team_name,  abs(football$home_score-football$home_score) )

Comment: @mr.joshuagordon Thank you very much, that will nearly work, but I need to know which team won.

Comment: winner <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(football)) {
  winner[i] <- as.character(data.frame(football_home_continent, football$away_continent)[i,which.max(data.frame(football$home_score,football$away_score))])
  
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 football$score_diff <- abs(football$home_score - football$away_score)
 football$winner <- ifelse(football$home_score > football$away_score, as.character(football$home), 
                      ifelse(football$result == "d", NA, as.character(football$away)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save some typing in this way. You first get score differences and winners. When the result indicates `w`, home is the winner. So you do not have to look into scores at all. Once you add the score difference and winner, you can subset your data by subsetting data with `max()`.

```
mydf <- read.csv(file="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iTXdPvGf", 
                 header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
mydf <- head(mydf,n = 48L)

library(dplyr)

mutate(mydf, scorediff = abs(home_score - away_score),
             winner = ifelse(result == "w", as.character(home),
                         ifelse(result == "l", as.character(away), "draw"))) %>%
filter(scorediff == max(scorediff))

#      home home_continent home_score        away away_continent away_score result scorediff      winner
#1 Cameroon         Africa          0     Croatia         Europe          4      l         4     Croatia
#2    Spain         Europe          1 Netherlands         Europe          5      l         4 Netherlands
#3  Germany         Europe          4    Portugal         Europe          0      w         4     Germany
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option without using `ifelse` for creating the "winner" column.  This is based on row/column indexes.  The numeric column index is created by matching the result column with its unique elements (`match(football$result,..`), and the row index is just `1:nrow(football)`.  Subset the "football" dataset with columns 'home', 'away' and `cbind` it with an additional column 'draw' with NAs so that the 'd' elements in "result" change to NA.

```
football$score_diff <- abs(football$home_score - football$away_score)
football$winner <-  cbind(football[c('home', 'away')],draw=NA)[ 
    cbind(1:nrow(football), match(football$result, c('w', 'l', 'd')))]

football[with(football, score_diff==max(score_diff)),]
#  home home_continent home_score    away away_continent away_score   result
 #60 Brazil  South America          1 Germany         Europe          7    l
 #   score_diff  winner
 #60          6 Germany
```

If the dataset is very big, you could speed up the `match` by using `chmatch` from `library(data.table)`

```
library(data.table)
chmatch(as.character(football$result), c('w', 'l', 'd'))
```

NOTE: I used the full dataset in the link